# Google services json file missing even after pasting

Tags: android, firebase

I am integrating firebase into my android project and have copy pasted the google-services.json file in the app directory.. but on syncing it still shows error.. can some please help me out..here is the link to my screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the file name seems to be incorrect. It contains a space before `.json`

Comment: show your app gradle file?

Comment: thanks.. @alim parker .. it worked very silly mistake from my side while renaming the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why u have two app folder. Make just one app folder. And remove space in file name